# The append method it's not correct?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, append

What the problem with my code ?
Please help
I tried several ide but still get same problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPRqA.jpg

Comment: Put a [mre] **in the question**, as text

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: What does _it's not correct_ mean, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `a=[]` outside the for loop to get all your elements added to your list

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? We can't help if we don't know your end goal.

you can try putting a outside of the loop and set:

```
for i in range(0, x):
```

instead of just numbers in a parenthesis.